# Is President of USA same as "leader of the free world"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage

I have seen and heard many people refer to the President of USA (POTUS) as "leader of the free world". e.g. ([link](http://www.theverge.com/2016/10/20/13352448/samsung-president-obama-galaxy-note-7-joke-obamacare-speech))

> Poor Samsung. Even the leader of the free world won’t spare them from
>   ridicule.

What is the historical significance of this phrase? Where is the usage of this phrase acceptable? Can it be used in serious publications, perhaps an official document etc.?

Comment: Anyone who wants to can say something like that (at least outside of countries which punish free speech).

Comment: OP, quite so! But for how much longer?

Comment: "Same as"? That's a philosophical question, but yes, the leader of the free world' is a common way to refer to the president of the US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be an informal epitheh that dates back to the Cold War period; ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leader%20of%20the%20free%20world&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleader%20of%20the%20free%20world%3B%2Cc0)*** shows a considerable increase in usage especially from the early 
'60s:

***[The leader of the free world](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+leader+of+the+free+world)***:

> - ***The United States of America, especially in relation to international polics***. (Sometimes capitalized.) *Ever since the Cold War, America has prided itself on being known as the Leader of the Free World.*

The Free Dictionary

***The leader of the free world***:

> - It's a hold-over from the early days of the Cold War when Europe was still in recovery from WWII and the U.S. was the prevailing democratic superpower. ***The President of the United States, as chief executive of the superpower and its military, was thus described as the "leader of the free world," basically by default of the weakness of the other democratic powers.***
> - The descriptor might have fallen out of favor entirely after the fall of the Soviet Union and the rise of a multi-polar world, but ***it got a spike in popularity after 9/11 as the U.S. took the lead in the Global War on Terrorism.***

From: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-President-of-the-United-States-of-America-sometimes-referred-to-as-the-leader-of-the-free-world)

The phrase is based on the notion of a ***[Free World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_World)*** that became common after WWII:

> - During World War II, the Allied powers viewed themselves as opposing the oppression and fascism of the Axis powers, thus making them "free". ***Following the end of World War II, the Cold War conception of the "Free World" included only capitalist particularly anti-communist states as being "free" and having such freedoms as free speech, free press, freedom to protest and freedom of association***.

From: Wikipedia

Comment: Did not know of Ngram. Cool!

Comment: Ironically, of course, the Cold War was a time when America wasn't very 'free' at all!